# Hypothesis needed for existence of an interval without a function zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

While studying ODE I thought of the following problem:

Let $f:A\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $x_0\in A$ such that $f(x_0)=0$. What properties should have $f$ so as to allow us to conclude that there exists $x_1\in A/x_1>x_0$ and $f(x_1)\neq0$ such that for all $a\in (x_0,x_1)$ is $f(a)\neq 0$?

I know that $f$ being strictly increasing is enough, but I was thinking about smoothness conditions like being continuous or differentiable, etc.

Every try I made was discarded by the following counterexample for $x_0=0$: \begin{equation}f(x)=x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right) \end{equation} for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One sufficient condition would be that $f$ is continuously differentiable with $f^\prime(x_0) > 0$.

**Reasoning:** Because $f^\prime$ is continuous and $f^\prime(x_0) > 0$ you will find a neighborhood of $x_0$ where $f^\prime$ is strictly positive. In this neighborhood $f$ is strictly increasing so that your property is fulfilled...